# MongoDB find center of array of points

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have 2 collections `lands` and `users`,

with `lands` looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": "locationID1",  # the string is "STRING" that could be referred in applicant collection
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [100, 100]
    }
},
{
    "_id": "locationID2", 
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [101, 101]
    }
}
```

and `users` like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("someRandomByteString")
    "name": "name",
    "owned_lands": ['locationID1', 'locationID2']
}
```

My goal is to create a `center` field that is also a point, representing the center of the `owned_lands`, so I can perform a `$geoNear` search by name later. The desired output:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("someRandomByteString")
    "name": "name",
    "owned_lands": ['locationID1', 'locationID2'],
    "center": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [100.5, 100.5]
    }
}
```

I tried to use `$lookup` on users to applicant:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "lands",
        localField: "owned_lands",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "detailedLands",
    },
}])
```

However mongoDB only supports single element to array lookup search, the other way around will return an empty array. What can I do to complete the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `$lookup` pipeline to get only the data you need, with the formatting you need:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "lands",
      localField: "owned_lands",
      foreignField: "_id",
      pipeline: [
        {$project: {
            _id: 0,
            x: {$first: "$location.coordinates"},
            y: {$last: "$location.coordinates"}
        }}
      ],
      as: "detailedLands"
  }},
  {$set: {
      center: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [{$avg: "$detailedLands.x"}, {$avg: "$detailedLands.y"}]
      },
      detailedLands: "$$REMOVE"
  }},
  { $merge : { into : "users" } }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o9vzte6dwI0)

Comment: Thanks for your emergency help!! This does work like a charm! Yet, mongodb updateMany does not support $lookup as I try to update the original data. Right now I'm looping over results and updateOne...which takes around 10 min (very slow). I wonder if you could kindly show how to update the data as well. Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure, just add a `$merge` step. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Hi @nimrod, could you also look at the other step with $geoNear I encountered? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75004277/geonear-with-pipeline-from-official-documentation-does-not-seem-to-work