# $geoNear with pipeline from official documentation does not seem to work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I was browsing through documentation about geoNear examples, and this particular snippets does not work, raising error: `$geoNear requires a 'near' option as an Array`

Sample Link: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

Sample :

```
db.places.insertMany( [
   {
      name: "Central Park",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.97, 40.77 ] },
      category: "Parks"
   },
   {
      name: "Sara D. Roosevelt Park",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9928, 40.7193 ] },
      category: "Parks"
   },
   {
      name: "Polo Grounds",
      location: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9375, 40.8303 ] },
      category: "Stadiums"
   }
] )
```

Do the aggregation:

```
db.places.aggregate( [
   {
      $lookup: {
         from: "places",
         let: { pt: "$location" },
         pipeline: [
            {
               $geoNear: {
                  near: "$$pt",
                  distanceField: "distance"
               }
            }
         ],
         as: "joinedField"
      }
   },
   {
      $match: { name: "Sara D. Roosevelt Park" }
   }
] );
```

What is the correct way to do the aggregation then?

---

Edit: MongoDB compass screen shot
[image: create spatial index on 'center']
[image: the problem]

---

Edit 2: the other approach I tried
[image]

---

The snippets I used on VS code playground:

```
use('hello');

db.world.drop();

db.world.insertMany([
  {
  'PRSN': '099HP0002',
  'address': 'nan',
  'applicantCategory': 'company',
  'applicantName': 'companyNameA',
  'buildingAdmins': 'nan',
  'buildingOwners': 'nan',
  'center': {'coordinates': [120.36521, 23.20558], 'type': 'Point'},
  'georeferencedParcels': ['433300860001'],
  },
  {
  'PRSN': '099HP0005',
  'address': 'nan',
  'applicantCategory': 'company',
  'applicantName': 'companyNameB',
  'buildingAdmins': 'nan',
  'buildingOwners': 'nan',
  'center': {'coordinates': [120.33333, 23.20555], 'type': 'Point'},
  'georeferencedParcels': ['433300860004'],
  },
  {
  'PRSN': '099HP0008',
  'address': 'nan',
  'applicantCategory': 'company',
  'applicantName': 'companyNameC',
  'buildingAdmins': 'nan',
  'buildingOwners': 'nan',
  'center': {'coordinates': [120.40000, 23.20551], 'type': 'Point'},
  'georeferencedParcels': ['433300860004'],
  }
]);

db.world.createIndex( { center: "2dsphere" } )

db.world.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "world",
      let: {
        pt: "$center"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: "$$pt",
            distanceField: "distance"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joinedField"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      name: "companyNameB"
    }
  }
])
```

[image]

Comment: When I copy/paste the code from the question to my mongosh shell connected to a  MongoDB 6.0.3 server, it runs correctly.  Did you create a 2dsphere index on location?

Comment: Yes, I have updated images with the data I use in my case, basically I only switched the 'location' name to 'center'. ( I do suspect the problem and used location at first, still not work)

Comment: What tool/version is giving you that error? What version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: I'm using the latest MongoDB Compass

Comment: I can confirm @Joe's observation that your provided query is [working fine](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y4f3oh9coGy). Noticing there are subtle differences in your screenshots and the provided query, can you share the exact document and query you are using in compass?

Comment: That query does _not_ work fine in the latest version of Compass.  This would appear to be a bug.  If you paste the query into mongosh, or use something other than compass it seems to work.

Comment: @ray the playground is working just fine, however I saw you using 'enum' as location's type, I feel like it's the key that it works?

Comment: @Joe: I've once again updated the query and full data I used.